# iOS Universal Links stop working after "Open in new tab" in safari

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

If a user long-taps on a URL that is a Universal Link in Safari and chooses to "Open in New Tab", the link opens in a new tab, as expected, but has the unexpected side-effect of not being able to use Universal Links for that app in the future.

Is there any way to make it work back (from an app or from the web site) after this?

Comment: The way to make it work again is to do the same thing, but choose "Open in [App Name]".

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it happens only if I don't put `UIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKey : @(YES)` options

Comment: How can you put this option in Safari? You can't, only from an app.